# How to make LinkedIn stop sneaking into my email contacts?

Tags: account-management, linkedin

When I look at which people which invitations are pending from people that actually sent me them I notice that there is below a "People you may know" category with among them people that actually aren't on LinkedIn but whom I can "add to network" by sending them an invitation to get an account on LinkedIn.

These are actually people from my contact from my email server. I want LinkedIn to stop sneaking into my email contacts.

Is there a way to disable LinkedIn knowing who are my contacts?

I probably synchronised my email contacts, is there a way to do the reverse?

Comment: "Is there a way to unable LinkedIn knowing which are my contacts?" - Connect your Linkin to an account with none of your contacts or just stop using Linkin

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily your E-mail list they're interconnecting you from. 
Check

Profile | Privacy and Settings | Third party apps to see if they're linking into your address lists from somewhere.

While you're there also check the Privacy tab | Data privacy and advertising section and adjust connection based on email and connection based on phone number.